# Import/Export variable containing Template Literals in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am segmenting code and have a array of object containing template literals. When I move the code to separate file and import it i get an error because my template literal isn't defined. If I define it in the export it stays the same when I import it. However, this works fine if the data is contained in the module it self.

**How do I do this the correct way?**

Export

```
const name = "temporary"

export const my_questions = [
  {
    id: 0, question: `What is ${name}'s favorite animal?`, alternative: [
      { answers: "Cat", img: "href" },
      { answers: "Dog", img: "href" },
      { answers: "Bird", img: "href" },
    ]
  }
]

export default {
  my_questions
}
```

Import

```
import {my_questions} from './data/data_questions'

function App(){

 const TemplateTest = ({name, my_questions}) => {
    return (
      <>
         { my_questions.map(x => <p>{x.question}</p>) }
      </>
    )
  }

   return (
     <div>
        <TemplateTest name="Rusty" my_questions={my_questions}/>
        // What is temporary's favorite animal?
     </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: The code in your questions works as expected. Are we talking about moving `const name` elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, to the props preferably

Comment: In that case you have to use a function instead. `question: name => \`What is ${name}'s favorite animal?\`` then use `x.question(name)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris G's answer, solved the problem.

```
export const my_questions = [
  {
    id: 0, question: name => `What is ${name}'s' favorite  animal?`, alternative: [
      { answers: "Cat", bild: "href" },
      { answers: "Dog", bild: "href" },
      { answers: "Bird", bild: "href" },
    ]
  }
]

export default {
  my_questions
}
```